# distinguish between paths starting from different nodes

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have the foolowing graph pf size (i,j) with two types of nodes : 
   `i` is the number of nodes of type S and `j` is the number of nodes of type O

```
  i=input('i:');
    j=input('j');

    B=randi([0 1], i*2,j);    
    nNodeCol = size(B,2);                            % nodes of type O
    nNodeLine = size(B,1)/2;                         % nodes of type S
    % First the 'O' nodes, then the 'S' nodes:
    nodeNames = [cellstr(strcat('O',num2str((1:size(B,2))'))) ; cellstr(strcat('S',num2str((1:size(B,1)/2)')))];
    nodeNames{end+1} = 'X';
    % Adjacency matrix adj, adj(i,j)=1 means there is an edge from node#i to node#j:
    adj = zeros(nNodeCol+nNodeLine);                 % square matrix which size is the number of nodes
    adj(1:nNodeCol, nNodeCol+1:end) = B(1:2:end,:)'; % edge from a 'O'node to 'S' node is added for all the 1 in the first line of the node in the matrix
    adj(nNodeCol+1:end, 1:nNodeCol) = B(2:2:end,:);  % edge from the 'S' node to 'O' node is added for all the 1 in the second line of the node in the matrix
    adj(end+1,end+1) = 0;  % add 1 row and 1 column to adj
    adj(end, 1:nNodeCol) = 1;  % only outgoing edges from X to O*
    % Creation of the graph:
    G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
    v = dfsearch(G,'X');
```

Now, this code will allow me to get `dfsearch` results starting from all nodes of type 'O' simultaneously . My question is the following : Is there any way to distinguish between the results , I mean to distinguish between the results of 'O1' and those of 'O2' and goes on ?

Comment: `dfsearch` is not how you "find all paths", it's how you discover all connected nodes. Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do and what output you expect with an example.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? What results are you expecting that are different from what you got before?

Comment: I got the vertex list .....my problem is to highlight every result .....I want to distinguish between the results of 'O1' , results for 'O2' and go on .

Comment: @StamDad: Are you trying to do this all in one graph? That's not likely to work since the search paths are going to overlap one another. How will you color an edge that is on multiple search paths?

Comment: @StamDad There's nothing about that in your question. Perhaps you should edit that in with exactly how you want to distinguish between the results for the different nodes. Note that the node discovery list returned by `dfsearch` will not contain all of the paths between the start node and its descendants.

Comment: @beaker ....I dont need all the paths ...I need just to know the existance of a path ..I think `dfsearch` can do that .....and I will edit my question .

Comment: @StamDad Then I would suggest that "we know that in order to find all paths..." and "if I want to search all the paths..." are a bit misleading.

Comment: @gnovice.....that's my question ....Is there any way ? in one plot or in multiple plots ? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a block diagonal matrix from `nNodeCol` copies of the adjacency matrix (corresponding to O1 O2 ...) and a dummy element ,so the new graph will have `nNodeCol*(nNodeCol+nNodeLine)+1` nodes. Then you can connect the first element of the first block , second element of the second block... to the end ,dummy, node.
Starting the search from the end element all subgraphs starting from `O`  elements can be found.

```
n =nNodeCol+nNodeLine;

adj = zeros(n);                                  %same as your code
adj(1:nNodeCol, nNodeCol+1:end) = B(1:2:end,:)'; %same as your code
adj(nNodeCol+1:end, 1:nNodeCol) = B(2:2:end,:);  %same as your code

adj2= blkdiag(kron(eye(nNodeCol),adj),0);            % block diagonal matrix of tha adjacency matrix plus a dummy element added to the end
adj2(end, 1:n+1:nNodeCol*n) = 1;              % conncet the dummy element to O1, O2..
G = digraph(adj2);                   
v = dfsearch(G,nNodeCol*n+1);                 % start the seach from the end node
v = v(2:end);                                 % exclude the dummy node from the result
categ= cumsum(ismember(v,1:n+1:nNodeCol*n));  % create categories so each subgraph can be distiguished
node_num = mod(v,n);                   % rescale node numbers to the original ones
```

`categ` is a vector of categories related to each subgraph.

Comment: I already tried that. Apparently that's not what the OP wants. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044664/1377097

Comment: @beaker I didn't see your well explained answer. So it seems that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: No problem, just letting you know that we might not have all of the information yet. :)